# tkinter button not showing IN the frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to learn tkinter (python3). I've created 2 frames and 2 buttons. It should display a button in each frame, but it's not. The buttons show up in the left upper corner of the window, and not in the display. How should I fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("test")
root.iconbitmap ("favicon.png")
root.geometry("1000x1000")

frame1= LabelFrame(root, height=300, width=300, text="dit is een frame", padx=250, pady=250).place(x=1,  y=1)
frame2= LabelFrame(root, height=300, width=300, text="dit is ook een frame", padx=250, pady=250).place(x=305,  y=1)

def msgbox1():
    c = messagebox.showinfo(title="test", message="testbericht")

b = Button(frame1, text="klik hier niet", command = msgbox1).grid()
b2 = Button(frame2, text="klik hier niet", command = msgbox1).grid()

#programmaloop starten
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: ALL of your variables related to widgets (`frame1`, for example) are actually None - the result of calling `.place()` or `.grid()`, NOT the actual widget.  Passing None as the first parameter to a widget makes it a child of the root window.  You need to do the geometry management as a separate statement.

Comment: Does this help? b = Button(frame1, text="klik hier niet", command = msgbox1).place(x=10,  y=30)
b2 = Button(frame2, text="klik hier niet", command = msgbox1).place(x=315,  y=30)

Comment: Thank you toyota supra, it does fix it. But, i think it is no solution when the frame is being moved, the buttons are again outside the frame.

Comment: Thanks jasonharper, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You want button below frame? Not inside frame?

Comment: If yes. Then change y-axis to specify location.

Comment: No i want the button in the frame on it’s own grid. So when the position of the frame changes, the button remains on the grid position in the frame ( so it moves along with the frame?